# Update wordpress users_meta table with information from another table

Tags: sql, wordpress

We have a custom table "crm" that gets updated daily from our ERP system.

The crm table has the fields  customerid, customertype

I need to update the meta_key 'user_type' to the customertype from crm.

I need to come up with the fastest least resource way to accomplish this. I am not the best at sql so my way is the worst.

1. Select all rows from the crm.
2. Loop through all rows and find the user_id (from wordpress) where the meta_key = crm.'custid'
3. Update user_meta SET meta_value = crm.customertype WHERE user_id = user_id

This will thousands of queries and certainly a resource hog. Any help would be much apprecaited.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do this in partitions- and CTE, Also do think about selecting only the columns you need from crm, ie: do you really need all the columns from crm table? Also consider using Explicit SQL Server transaction which enables you to see if you'll get any errors using the update (https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-rollback-using-explicit-sql-server-transactions/)
:

```
BEGIN TRAN

WITH cte_crm AS (
SELECT DISTINCT customerid, customertype
FROM table_crm 
WHERE 'date_column' = '2023-05-16' /*you can specify the date for today here if you are updating daily values - else you can specify a period when looking up historical values*/
)
UPDATE user_meta
set user_meta.meta_value =crm.customertype
from table_user_meta user_meta
inner join cte_crm crm
on user_meta.customerid= c.customerid

ROLLBACK TRAN /* get rid of ROLLBACK TRAN once you're happy with the results and replace it with COMMIT TRAN to implement the update*/
```